# How to calculate the consecutive sum of number in a string?

Tags: java

I would like to find the sum of integer in string. For example:

```
String myString= "The price is 345and the tax1 is 12sales";
String output = "The price is 12and the tax1 is 3sales";
```

I found few approaches none is displaying the final output the way I need.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int I =0; i < myString.lengh(); i++)
{
   char c = myString.charAt(i);
   if(Character.isDigit(c))
   {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
   }
}
```

I am getting the total sum but I would like to be able to append the string with individual sums.
    output = "The price is 12and the tax1 is 3sales"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a StringBuilder for building the result string. You have to keep adding the digits as long as you encounter digits. When you encounter a character, you have to append the sum at hand (if you have) and then append the character.

*Note:* This won't work if the sum can be 0 (and needs to be tweaked to support that).

```
int sum = 0;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
{
    char c = myString.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isDigit(c))
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
    } else {
        if (sum != 0) {
            builder.append(sum);
        }
        builder.append(c);
        sum = 0; //reset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an if statement checking the next character for a digit, if it's a digit add it, otherwise you are done and can print it.
However, your input is quite unusual, are you sure you can not improve the input itself?